# Pass/indent each line from .txt file as parameter value in python function

Tags: python, api, parameter-passing

The title says it all, I have a users.txt file, I want to pass each line as a parameter to screen_name='$' and run the script in loop. I read some tutorials and googled the answer but didn't found what I was looking for.

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, **screen_name='user'**).items():

Comment: Maybe you should begin with the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) before you do more complicated things.

Comment: I already went thru some tutorials but didn't figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a file is opened for input in Python, iterating over it returns each line as a string.

As such, you can really simply achieve what you want something like the following:

```
with open('users.txt') as f:
    for user in f:
        for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name=user).items():
            # do something with `tweet`
```

---

**NOTE**: being unfamiliar with `tweepy`, I'm assuming that the syntax is otherwise correct.